# Reference a shared library project to xamarin forms pcl project

Tags: c#, c++, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, shared-libraries

I have a Xamarin Forms project in which I want to use native android library. Therefore, I created a shared library project and added this project to my XamarinForms project by referencing it. Then in  MainActivit.cs file in myProject.droid, I tried to use this library with the following method:

```
public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    [DllImport("libSharedLibrary.so", EntryPoint = "AndroidInfo")]

    public static extern string AndroidInfo();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        ...
        var tool = AndroidInfo();
    }
}
```

There is no specific function that I want to use at this level, I just want to reach `"libSharedLibrary.so"` from my .droid project. However it throws an exception saying `System.DllNotFoundException: libSharedLibrary.so`. What could be the reason for it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You could read [Binding a Java Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/)  and [Using Native Libraries](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/).

Comment: I forgot to add the path of .so file to my .csproj, above link solved my problem, thank you very much.

Comment: Happy coding. : )